# How can I activate the sourcemap for Vue-Cli 4?

Tags: vue.js, source-maps, vue-cli-4

I believed the `npm run serve` command use the sourcemap by default for the js, but it seems not because I always see `vue.runtime.esm.js:619`.

I made a vue.config.js file at the root level project.

I try two things:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: config => {
          config.devtool = 'source-map'
    }
}
```

and:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map'
    }
}
```

None of them works. I still stuck with `vue.runtime.esm.js:619` which is useless.

Does anyone know how really activate the source-map with vue-cli 4?

Comment: According to the manual: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-sourcemap

Comment: have you solved this problem? @GBMan How to solved it?

Answer (score 4):

Using the generated vue.config.js from vue-cli v4 (generating a vue 3 project) It provided me this file:

```js
// vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
})
```

I then modified it to this:

```js
// vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  }
})
```

Which works enough for me to enable VSCode debugging in Chrome/Electron.

*Edit
The error you are getting may be unrelated to source-maps and related to warnings from vue itself.
For example

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6584
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: AMadeUpComponentName
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <MyView onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Unfortunately this is a limitation of vue.  However, improvements have been made between VueJS v2 and v3.  Finally, I couldn't find an original source, but I read that improving the warning messages to track down the cause of warnings and errors is a high priority feature.

## * Edit 10/12/2022

I had an older project that this answer didn't solve at all.  After a `yarn upgrade` and `@vue/cli` upgrading, this configuration began working again!

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes my sourcemaps working again with Vue CLI v4!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `ProjectOptions` `chainWebpack` property.

```
  chainWebpack?: (config: ChainableWebpackConfig) => void;
```

---

Try the following in your `vue.config.js` file:

```
/** @type import('@vue/cli-service').ProjectOptions */

module.exports = {
  // https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/tree/v4#getting-started
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.devtool('source-map')
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I try it and I get always the vue.runtime.esm.js:619 :\
How can I be sure my vue.config.js is used?